# When I add status bar below component get hide in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In my App, I have Main.js file as the main component which is not visible when `StatusBar` added in the `View`.

Code:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
                <View >
                    <StatusBar
                        backgroundColor="blue"
                        barStyle="light-content"
                        hidden ={false}
                    />
                    <Main />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this `<View>` component is made by you? If so could you please send us the component's code

Comment: No View is a predefined tag in React Native I have only Created <Main/>

Comment: Can you replace View with div?

Comment: I think you should post the <Main /> component's code. So we can know what it is really.